# Etymology of "to be cuter than a monkey with a puppy"

Tags: etymology, idioms

I think that this is an idiom, but I didn't find any explanations. I wonder about the *monkey*. Just *to be cuter than a puppy* would be clear. *Monkey*'s (if it refers to the animal) are known for being silly or a bit stupid, primitive. Doesn't it have a slight negative connotation?

Why is it called "*to be cuter than a monkey with a puppy*"?

Comment: Apparently [someone called **Bones**](http://www.fanpop.com/spots/bones/forum/post/7104/2/favorite-bones-quote) said it. I have no idea who Bones is, but I'm voting to close as "too localised". Or it could be "general reference" - both monkeys and puppies are considered cute, and that's pretty common knowledge.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not an idiom. It's a writer being creative.

Monkeys are cute. Puppies are cute. A monkey *with* a puppy must be very cute indeed.

If in your culture, monkeys aren't seen as cute - well, the writer wasn't writing for you.